# How to access localhost on a chromebook

Tags: android, google-chrome, localhost, google-chrome-os

I'm using Spck editor on a Google Chromebook to do some coding (localhost:7700), but localhost isn't working when trying to preview in browser. I just get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You did not tell why you were refused. There must be a reason. There was a connection. Look in the logs.

Comment: You are using the Linux Container aka, the Terminal app? Are you using the device browser or an Android browser or a browser from another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Get an alternative browser e.g Firefox(worked for me).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).